# What might cause TexMaker to look like this?

Tags: texmaker

See image below.

No matter how many times I uninstall and reinstall TeXMaker, it keeps showing up with that layout instead of the typical one. It started happening recently and I am clueless about the issue.

I am not asking just for the sake of getting it back to normal, but because I am afraid that whatever caused this change might have changed other stuff in the software's performance.

[image: TeXMaker's appearance]

Edit: The typical one would be the one featured on the website of TeXMaker: http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/

Comment: What is the "typical" one??

Comment: Instead of what? The only thing changed I can see is that the left pane is minimized. Please be a bit more specific

Comment: If you are talking about the visual, probably you are using it with the system theme. Do you want that blue theme? Go to the Option menu and then Configure. To see the left panel, click on the Structure button on the bottom, near the status bar.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the visual, probably you are using it with the System Theme.

Do you want that blue theme? Go to the **Options** menu and then **Configure TeXmaker** and then **Editor**.

Or to see the left panel **Structure**, click on the 'Structure' button at the bottom (see the red marks).

[image]

[image]

The image below show that two panels are on (dark grey color) and other two are off (light grey color).

To open the PDF file with an external viewer click on the button at the top right corner (red mark).

[image]